# Can't log in to Drupal websites after upgrading to OSX Yosemite

Tags: 7, users

I have just upgraded my local machine to OSX Yosemite which has changed my Apache version from 2.2 to 2.4 and my PHP version from 5.4 to 5.5.

When I visit both example.dev/user and example.dev/user/login and enter my username and password, the login form appears to post the data and then 'loops' back to it's original state i.e. blank fields.

This is the same across all websites and all browsers and is the same for all users.

There is nothing in any of the error logs but…

```
"POST /user HTTP/1.1" 404 16744
```

… in the access logs

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks,

S

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Does the example.com you used mean the virtual domain you use at your local machine?  Or is your local machine hosting the website at example.com and any browser on the Internet to access to it can not view the contents?

Comment: Clive: Nothing in the error logs.

Comment: Masa: Sorry yes, example.com on my local machine using vhosts... a better example would be example.dev

Comment: @StephenWilson A 404 for a POST on the /user page? Yes, that's related :)

Comment: The rewrite module is enabled...that happen to me when I updated to Yosemite. I had to configure it everything again.

Comment: @Clive but I don't get a 404 page returned?

Comment: @cayerdis please can you tell me how you fixed this?

Comment: @StephenWilson Maybe you've got a module installed the displays the login form for all 404s? To enable mod_rewrite, uncomment the line for the mod_rewrite extension in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: @Clive Yes, uncommenting LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so has worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the answers/suggestions provided.

To fix my specific problem i.e. not being able to log in after upgrading to Yosemite (Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5), you need to edit your httpd.conf file, uncommenting the following line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

(Line 168 in my httpd.conf)

Then restart Apache using `sudo apachectl restart` command.

Answer (score 3):

That happen to me when I upgraded to OSX Yosemite. I had to reconfigure my apache to make it work. Make sure that the rewrite module in apache is enabled, that you are allowing override. I had a similar problem also with mysql. I had to reinstall again.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue w/ my Drupal install after upgrading...Also had a codeigniter site disappear b/c of the new OS re-writing all my apache directives...I found this article is super-useful in going back thru re-initializing apache server for OS X Yosemite...

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/